# Is there a way to get a substring with a keyword in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a problem where I want to copy a URL from a message, where the URL is not clickable.
I tried the following:

```
${email}=    Get Text    css:.msg-body
${url}=    Get Substring    ${email}    413    516
```

The code works, but the problem is that it may happen that the URL is placed in a different position, not between characters 413 and 516.

Is there a way to copy the URL based on a keyword, for example the start would be 'https'?

Comment: I can imagine regexp would be an option.

Comment: you can use javascript executor to highlight the element

Comment: Please rename the question `highlighting` rather means adding a border or backgroud to the text. What you are looking for is getting a substring of a text.

Answer (score 1):

As @pavelsaman say, regex would be suitable.
In it's simplest form `https.*`
`${url}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${email}    https://.*`

`.` stands for match of any type of character.
`*` stand for zero or more of the preceding character.

This is a very greedy expression and will match from `https` to the end since it will match one or zero of any character after `https`.

If possible it is better to make the expression more strict by adding some end expression as well.

I think this page is good for regex elaboration.
https://regex101.com/

And please notice that in Robot Framework you might need to escape backslashes `\` with another backslash `\`.
[BuiltIn - Pattern Matching](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Pattern%20matching)